# Is ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush no longer necessary when the signal becomes stable?

Tags: angular

Signals, introduced in Angular 16, is introduced to have even more optimized performance compared to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. However, I heard that it is still in the Developer preview phase and may not function completely.

If this API becomes stable, will ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush no longer be necessary?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

Signals works in pair with the change detection strategy. Their purpose is to control when the change detection should trigger.

If you do not use onPush, your change detection will still run very often, as it is to be expected.

If you switch to onPush, your change detection runs only when instructed to (timeouts, cdRef, observables, etc).

in that matter, signals are only a new way of triggering change detection, which is more granular, as they explain in their documentation and blog posts. It simply means they're more optimized.

So to answer you, no, you will have to keep using onPush, even when you use signals.

Comment: what if you remove onPush and apply the solution with signals? Will it re-render all subtrees of the application?
And what will the behavior be like if you don't apply the solution without signs?
Is the performance great?

Comment: If you remove onpush and use signals, angular keeps checking for changes sporadically, depending on your user actions, and depending on how you coded your component. Thus, it CAN re-render all subtrees. The point of signals is that they will re-render a specific part of the component, only when needed, and not call it for the parents. If you want the full "signal experience" (only signals control your detection), then you need to go zoneless.

Comment: To sum it up, signals go along with change detection, they do not remplace it. If you want to replace the onpush strategy, you have to implement a custom zone, or go zoneless.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the "OnPush" strategy will remain crucial for the foreseeable future until Angular adopts Signal based components which is similar to standalone component (which you can set by adding "signals: true") by using the syntax in the component decorator, you can flip and the change detection mechanism. But even with this improvement, I believe that the "OnPush" strategy will still be necessary. As long as you have complex components, it's safe to say that "OnPush" will continue to be relevant as long as Angular still using zone.js.

You can read more about the [Angular RFC on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682).